# Confusion about neat way to construct invariant measures on certain manifolds

Tags: measure-theory

I found some notes online about a measure on the mass shell that is invariant under Lorentz transformations and the author said that its construction was similar to the measure on the sphere that is invariant under rotations.

I will try to illustrate that construction below on $S^1$, but I am misunderstanding this geometric type of argument for constructing a measure, so It would be awesome if someone could help me out to explain/reference what is going on in a formal way.

**Idea:** We enlarge $S^1$ to the annulus $$S_{\epsilon}^1 = \{(t, p): 1 \leq t^2 + p^2 \leq (1+\epsilon)^2\}$$ and starting with 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure on annulus (which is invariant under rotations), we scale it appropriately and take a limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Then the resulting measure $\lambda$ on $S^1$ should be invariant under rotations and unique up to scalar multiple.

**Rough Details** We parametrize $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ by $f_{\pm}: [-1, 1] \rightarrow S^1$ where $f_{\pm}(p) = (\pm (1 - p^2)^{1/2}, p)$ so that $f_+$ and $f_-$ parametrize $S_+^1$ and $S_-^1$ (the right and left halves of $S^1$) respectively.

For now we consider only the right half of $S_+$ and for convencience write $f_+ = f = (f_1, f_2)$.

Consider a point $(t,p) \in S_+^1$. The "thickness" of the annulus through $(t, p)$, in the first parameter, is given by $$h(\epsilon) = \sqrt{(1+\epsilon)^2 - p^2} - \sqrt{1-p^2} = \sqrt{t^2 + 2\epsilon + \epsilon^2} - t$$ Using a Taylor expansion at $\epsilon = 0$, the thickness is given by $$h(\epsilon) = \frac{\epsilon}{t} + R(\epsilon)$$ where $R(\epsilon) \sim o(\epsilon)$and therefore $$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{h(\epsilon)}{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{t}$$

This is where I start getting confused. Intuitively, the tiny bit of area around $(t,p)$, $dm^2(t,p)$, is the thickness times the length, so $$dm^2(t,p) = h(\epsilon)dl(t,p)$$ where m is Lebesgue measure on the annulus and $l$ is the arc length measure on $S^1$. We can define $$d\lambda_{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{\epsilon} dm^2 = \frac{h(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}dl$$
Then as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, we get that $$d\lambda_{\epsilon}(t,p) \rightarrow \frac{1}{t} dl(t,p) = \lambda$$ in some sense, probably weakly. However, the notes I am looking at seem to suggest that the tiny bit of volume around $(t,p)$ is $$dm^2 = h(\epsilon)d(f_{*} m)$$ and that their $\lambda$ is $$\lambda_{\epsilon}(t,p) \rightarrow \frac{1}{t}d(f_{*}m)(t, p) = \lambda$$
I think this is what the notes are saying since the author wrote that for each $g$ on $S^1$,  we have $$\int g d\lambda = \int g (f(p)) \frac{1}{f_1(p)} dm(p)$$ which is eqivalent to $$ \int g(t,p) \frac{1}{t} d (f_* m)(t, p)$$

**Confusion:**
So I am confused on the physical inutition as to why the length of the volume element corresponds to the push forward of Lebesgue measure instead of the arc length measure. I think when they are pulled back the Radon-Nikodym derivative of one with respect to the other is a nonconstant density.

anyways, this seems like a really cool construction if I can figure out why it works.

---

**Edit:**  Here is an incorrect attempt at using Mason's response, if $M \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is an $m$-dimensional manifold invariant under some subgroup $G \subset GL_N(\mathbb{R})$ whose members satisfy $\det A = \pm 1$ for each $A \in G$. Then for each chart $(U, \phi)$ on $M$, and $A \in G$, $(A^{-1} U, \phi \circ A) $ is a chart on $M$ and

\begin{align*}
g_{A^{-1} \circ \phi^{-1}}(x) 
&= \det \bigg( [A^{-1} D\phi^{-1}(x)]^* [A^{-1} D\phi^{-1}(x)] \bigg) \\ 
&= \det \bigg(D\phi^{-1}(x)^* {A^{-1}}^* A^{-1} D\phi^{-1}(x) \bigg) \\ 
&= \det \bigg( {A^{-1}}^* A^{-1} \bigg) \det \bigg(D\phi^{-1}(x)^* D\phi^{-1}(x) \bigg) \hspace{.2cm} \textbf{this is not true in general, must fix}\\ 
&= (\det A)^{-2} \det \bigg( D\phi^{-1}(x)^* D\phi^{-1}(x) \bigg)  \\
&= \det \bigg( D\phi^{-1}(x)^* D\phi^{-1}(x) \bigg)  \\
&= g_{\phi^{-1}}(x) 
\end{align*}

So that for each $E \subset U$
\begin{align*}
\mu(A^{-1}E) 
&= \int_{\phi \circ A (A^{-1}E)} \sqrt{g_{A^{-1} \circ \phi^{-1}}(x) } dx \\
&= \int_{\phi (E)} \sqrt{g_{\phi^{-1}}(x) } dx \\
&= \mu(E)
\end{align*}
and so this measure is invariant under $G$

Comment: Isn't $\lambda$ the arclength measure, i.e. the measure on $S^1$ induced by the Euclidean metric? The arclength element is $dS(y) = \sqrt {\det Df(p)^T Df(p)}dm(p)$, which since $f$ is the graph of a function is known to be $\sqrt{1 + \lVert \nabla f(p) \rVert^2}dm(p)$, which I think is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - p^2}}dm(p)$.

Comment: @Mason I am glad you mentioned that. That is right and that formula you wrote lines up with the one from the notes too. Thanks for confirming. Now I just need to figure out the intuition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $M \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is an $m$-dimensional $C^1$ surface, that is, for any $p \in M$, there exists an open set $O$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$ and a $C^1$ diffeomorphism $\phi \colon O \to U$.  $U$ is called a coordinate patch, and $\phi$ is called a coordinate chart.

Given a Borel set $E \in B_U$, where $U$ is a coordinate patch with chart $\phi \colon O \to U$, we can define
$$\mu(E) = \int_{O}\chi_E(\phi(x))\sqrt{g(x)}\,dx = \int_{\phi^{-1}(E)}\sqrt{g(x)}\,dx,$$
where $g(x) = \det(D\phi(x)^*D\phi(x)) \in C(O)$. Using the change of variables theorem, it can be shown that $\mu(E)$ is independent of the chart $\phi$. Thus $\mu$ is a measure on the Borel sets of $U$. Writing $M$ as a countable disjoint union of sets contained in patches then gives a measure $\mu$ on the Borel sets of $M$ (again independent of the sets in the disjoint union). Using the $\sigma$-compactness of $M$, $\mu$ can be shown to be $\sigma$-finite. Then monotone convergence theorem shows that for any measurable $f \geq 0$ supported in a patch $U$, $$\int_{U}f\,d\mu = \int_{O}f(\phi(x))\sqrt{g(x)}\,dx$$

There is intuition for the factor $\sqrt{g(x)}$. Let $R \subset O$ be a small rectangle around a point $x$ (as in a Riemann sum say), with $\phi(x) = y \in U$. Then unrigorously, by linear approximation and assuming translation invariance, $\mu(\phi(R)) \approx \mu(\phi(x) + D\phi(x)(R - x)) = \mu(D\phi(x)R)$. Set $A = D\phi(x)$. Pick a linear isometry $P \colon A\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ (meaning $P^* = P^{-1}$). Then intuitively it would make sense to have $\mu(AR) = m(PAR)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^m$. We can compute
\begin{align}
m(PAR) &= |\det(PA)|m(R) \\
&= \sqrt{\det((PA)^*PA)}m(R) \\
&= \sqrt{\det(A^*P^*PA)}m(R) \\
&= \sqrt{\det(A^*A)}m(R).
\end{align}
Now let the size of $R$ go to $0$ to "get" $d\mu(y) = \sqrt{\det(D\phi(x)^*D\phi(x))}\,dx$.

Comment: Thanks for spelling that out! Im still confused about what the notes were saying, but after reading your answer and thinking about it, it seems like maybe the notes were over complicating this. If you have a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$ of dimension $m$ which is invariant under the action of a subgroup of $N \times N$ matrices of determinant $\pm 1$, then the surface measure you defined would also be invariant under pushing forward by a matrix in that subgroup since matrices of determinant $\pm 1$ dont change area correct? Or do I need the matrices to be orthogonal to preserve area?

Comment: I edited my question to reflect why your response implies what I wanted to show. Thanks again!

Comment: @CarsonJames In your proof it seems that you used $A^* = A^{-1}$. But this is not necessarily true, even if $\det(A) = \pm 1$. It seems like what you showed is that if $A \in GL(N, \mathbb{R})$, $AM \subset M$, and $A^* = A^{-1}$, then for any Borel set $E \subset M$, $\mu(E) = \mu(AE)$. A linear operator satisfying $A^* = A^{-1}$ is called orthogonal.

Comment: In my proof I was trying to use the fact that $\det A^* = \det A$ for real matrices $A$. I updated it to make that more explicit. Could you check it and tell me if it looks okay?

Comment: @CarsonJames It is not true in general that $\det(B^*A^*AB) = \det(A^*A)\det(B^*B)$, so I don't think your proof works.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying, the $D\phi(x)$ matrix isnt square, so I cant do that. Good catch, I will have to think a little harder about why the measure is invariant.

Comment: @CarsonJames The measure is not invariant under arbitrary $A \in GL(N, \mathbb{R})$ with determinant $\pm 1$. For a counterexample we can take $m = 1, N = 2$, $M = \{t(1, 0) \colon 0 < t < 1\}$, $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$ $M$ has length $1$, but $AM$ has length $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @CarsonJames Actually I realize that counterexample isn't strictly correct since $AM$ is not contained in $M$, but taking $A = \begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ works.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example there, I guess the measured described in the notes I am reading happened to coincide with the surface area measure on $S^1$. I tried working it out for the mass shell, but I got a nasty determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix that doesn't look like it reduces to what they had in the notes. So I will have to figure out what is going on another time. I did have one last idea, but it is pretty much a separate question, so Ill make another one. Thanks again for your help

Comment: One last thing, could you point me towards a reference for the formulas you gave for the surface area measure? I have never seen them before and I was wondering if they were from a calc III book or from higher up like a differential geometry book (which I am not super well versed in) and they were pretty handy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128056/discussion-between-mason-and-carson-james).